# Associate code behind with a master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: master-page, html, inheritance, conversion, codebehind

I want to associate some code behind with my master page by using the html/master conversion.

I added something like this just after `LocalBinding` in my html file:

```
<!--SPM:<%@ Master language="C#" Inherits=" [...] " %>-->
```

But the conversion process add this line in the master file:

```
<%@Master language="C#"%>
```

Is there a way to do this without adding programmatically the correct line to the master page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is possible when working with html design files that get converted to a master page. A code behind is custom code that needs to be deployed to the server. The Design Manager will not package this code when creating a Design Package. Design Packages are Sandbox solutions and Sandbox solutions do not support code behind (anymore).

**What can you do?**
Download the master page that you already have. (master page, not the html file). Create a Visual Studio farm solution. Add the master page to this solution together with your code-behind. Deploy this package to the server.

Depending on what your requirement are, you can also create a user-control in Visual Studio. Add your code to the suer-control. Deploy this user-control to the server as a farm solution and simply reference this (custom) user-control in your html master page. This way you can continue to work with the html page.